# Create Bitmap Options Using IndoorAtlas

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system

I have some following code :

```
void loadFloorPlanImage(FloorPlan floorPlan) {
BitmapFactory.Options options = createBitmapOptions(floorPlan);
FutureResult<Bitmap> result = ia.fetchFloorPlanImage(floorPlan, options);
result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Bitmap result) {
           // now you have floor plan bitmap, do something with it
           updateImageViewInUiThread(result);
        }
        // handle error conditions
}
}
```

What i'm getting confused is in line :

BitmapFactory.Options options = createBitmapOptions(floorPlan);

What i'm supposed gonna to do in 'createBitmapOptions' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an IndoorAtlas specific question. You can adjust eg the size of the bitmap image to be produced or simply leave the options null. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Sample might look like this if you wanted to restrict the maximum size of the image to be used in your app's map view:

```
private BitmapFactory.Options createBitmapOptions(FloorPlan floorPlan) {

    int reqWidth = 2048;
    int reqHeight = 2048;

    final int width = (int) floorPlan.dimensions[0];
    final int height = (int) floorPlan.dimensions[1];
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    return options;

}
```

Comment: i have following your code and get this result :
Process: skripsi.ubm.studenttracking, PID: 19086
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.graphics.BitmapFactory$Options.inSampleSize' on a null object reference
            at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor.createBitmapOptions(indoor.java:370)
            at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor.loadFloorPlanImage(indoor.java:322)
            at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor$1.onResult(indoor.java:163)
            at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor$1.onResult(indoor.java:159)